# Bad Request: QUERY_ID_INVALID telegram bot api

Tags: c#, telegram-bot

I Want use telegram api bot . every thing is ok (in my idea) but i have stupid error that where ever is search i cant find any thing .

I am using Inline mode .

```
  var awnser = new AnswerInlineQuery()
  {
     inline_query_id =model.inline_query.id,
     results = new List<InlineQueryResultArticle>()
  };
  awnser.results.Add(new InlineQueryResultArticle() { id = Guid.NewGuid().ToString("N"), type = "article", url = "fidilio", input_message_content = new InputTextMessageContent() { message_text = "salam" }, title = "test" });

  var send = SendInlineAwnser(awnser);
```

The send method is using restsharp

```
 var ser = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(data);
 var url = "https://api.telegram.org/bot" + telegramToken + "/answerInlineQuery";
 var req = SimplePost<AnswerInlineQuery>(ser, url);
```

my serlization out put is this

```
{"inline_query_id":"302418856930797437","results":[{"type":"article","id":"fae56651b23244f8a3be94b1e6ebf6e7","title":"test","input_message_content":{"message_text":"salam"},"url":"fidilio"}]}
```

Comment: If you are sure that model.inline_query.id is correct, then consider that 
you should send notify max 15 sec after inline keyboard pushed otherwise you will receive: Bad Request: QUERY_ID_INVALID

Comment: @ehsan.sardar can you explain me more ?

Comment: After user sends inline query to Telegram, it will receive unique inline query id which is valid for the next 15 seconds. If you send query results after this period, you will get invalid query Id

Comment: @Ehsan.Saradar can you give me as awnser ?

Answer (score 2):

make sure that model.inline_query.id is correct and if so, keep in mind that you can send notify max 15 sec after inline keyboard pushed. Besides, I suggest using async method for sending inline query results.

Comment: ok . let me i change method to async .  in this model take less tahn 15 seconds

Comment: Please Help me this link:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41519495/how-to-solve-disturbance-in-my-bot-in-c